# Need default password for MI424WR router

Tags: router, internet, passwords, reset

I've tried all combinations of admin/admin, admin/[blank], admin/password, admin/password1, admin/P@$$W0RD!, and all those.

I also tried the password that it has printed on the router itself numerous times, no luck.

I reset it using the 30/30/30 method which may not even apply to this router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to reset it again but after that, the password listed on the router worked. Not sure what it was when it wasn't working but it could have been the serial as Scott mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Per [this page on Verizon's website](http://www22.verizon.com/support/residential/internet/fiosinternet/networking/setup/vzmi424/120428.htm)

> **What are the default user name and password for my Verizon MI424WR
>   router?**
>
> The default user name for the Verizon MI424WR router is
>   "admin," and the default password is "password" (do not include the
>   quotation marks).
>
> Note: To improve security, your router password may have been changed to the serial number of your router if you have not changed
>   the password from the default of "password." You can find your
>   router's password on the label affixed to the bottom or back of your
>   router.
>
> If you reset your router to the factory default settings, the router
>   password will return to "password."

If Verizon is not the ISP who supplied the router the password could be different and you will need to contact your ISP (or check their website) for the default password. The reason for this is they can set the password to be anything they want when they load their custom firmware.

Answer (score 0):

The default password depends on who supplied the router. It is often `password` or `password1`, but it may also be the device serial number (which usually starts with `CS`).

To reset this router, leave it on for a few minutes. Then hold the reset button down for 30 seconds. Release it and wait a few minutes. You should then be able to get in with `admin`/`password`.

If that doesn't work, talk to whoever supplied you the router. Some companies customize it.

To my knowledge, the username is always `admin`.